# System.Transactions vs. MSDTC

Tags: .net, database, ado.net, transactionscope

What is possible with MSDTC but is not possible with System.Transactions (and TransactionScope)?

As I know MSDTC supports usage of one transaction from several processes but TransactionScope (with DependentTransaction) is limited to AppDomain. Is it true?

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Transactions provides enhanced performance with Dynamic Escalation and Promotable Enlistments. 
Please refer [msdn info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0abf6ykb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).